# In-App Billing: Inventory not correct; makes user purchase again

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Edit***
still looking for an answer to my original question.  Why won't Android see the item has been bought previously instead of making the user pay again?  Setting SharedPreferences is an OK idea, but what if the user uninstalls?  They would have to buy again.  I do not want this for the users.   Thank you.

I tried to figure out why the app does not inventory correctly, I took this from TrivialDrive and tried to make it my own.  I believe I removed all the consume and I only have one item to purchase; a premium upgrade.  This should be bought only once and never charged twice.  When I compile and run the app on my tablet I pass the purchase process OK and all seems well, until I use the task manager to close the app and re-open it.  Once it's re-opened it asks to purchase premium again instead of passing that and performing the premium function.

Here is the code:

```
public class myClass extends SherlockActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
ProgressBar pd = null;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

Spinner spLoadFrom;
WebView wv;
private LinearLayout container;
private Button nextButton, closeButton;
private EditText findBox;

private static final String TAG = "Web";
IabHelper mHelper;

static boolean mIsPremium = false;
boolean mIsUserPremium = false;
boolean searchAllowed = false;

static final String PREM_SKU = "prem";

private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter;

String name_free[] = { };

String displayName_free[] = {  };

String name_premium[] = { };
String displayName_premium[] = {};


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.fMenu);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    pd = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pBar);

    spLoadFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);

    if (mIsPremium == true) {
        spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName_premium);
    } else {
        spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName_free);
    }

    spinnerArrayAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    SpinnerListener spListener = new SpinnerListener();
    spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "hidden";
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of
            // stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu3, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(getMenuItem(item))) {
        return true;
    }

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.search) {
        if (searchAllowed == false) {

    } else if (itemId == R.id.contact) {
        emailme();
    } else if (itemId == R.id.rate) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
        Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find Play Market",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

public void buyPrem() {
    Log.d(TAG,
            "Upgrade button clicked; launching purchase flow for upgrade.");
    /*
     * TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See
     * the comments on verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is
     * a SAMPLE, we just use an empty string, but on a production app you
     * should carefully generate this.
     */
    String payload = "";

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, PREM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
            + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: "
                + purchase);
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            // Handle error
            return;

        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(PREM_SKU)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
            alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
            mIsPremium = true;
            mIsUserPremium = true;
            searchAllowed = true;
        }

    }
};

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        /*if (inventory.hasPurchase(PREM_SKU)) {

            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(PREM_SKU), null);
        }*/

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(PREM_SKU);
        mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
        Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
        if (mIsPremium) {
            searchAllowed = true;
            mIsUserPremium = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "Should be premium by now...");
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }

};

boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

    /*
     * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct.
     * It will be the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
     * 
     * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase
     * and verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will
     * fail in the case where the user purchases an item on one device and
     * then uses your app on a different device, because on the other device
     * you will not have access to the random string you originally
     * generated.
     * 
     * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
     * 
     * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different
     * between them, so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to
     * another user.
     * 
     * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app
     * wasn't the one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items
     * purchased by the user on one device work on other devices owned by
     * the user).
     * 
     * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across
     * app installations is recommended.
     */

    return true;
}

/*public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);

}*/

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            searchAllowed = false;
            //mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(PREM_SKU),
            //      mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {

        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null)
        mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

void complain(String message) {
    Log.e(TAG, "**** TrivialDrive Error: " + message);
    alert("Error: " + message);
}

void alert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    bld.setMessage(message);
    bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    Log.d(TAG, "Showing alert dialog: " + message);
    bld.create().show();
}

private android.view.MenuItem getMenuItem(final MenuItem item) {
    return new android.view.MenuItem() {
        @Override
        public int getItemId() {
            return item.getItemId();
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean collapseActionView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean expandActionView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ActionProvider getActionProvider() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getActionView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public char getAlphabeticShortcut() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupId() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable getIcon() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Intent getIntent() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ContextMenuInfo getMenuInfo() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public char getNumericShortcut() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public SubMenu getSubMenu() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getTitle() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getTitleCondensed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasSubMenu() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isActionViewExpanded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCheckable() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChecked() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isVisible() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setActionProvider(
                ActionProvider actionProvider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setActionView(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setActionView(int resId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setAlphabeticShortcut(char alphaChar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setCheckable(boolean checkable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setChecked(boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setIcon(Drawable icon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setIcon(int iconRes) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setIntent(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setNumericShortcut(char numericChar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setOnActionExpandListener(
                OnActionExpandListener listener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setOnMenuItemClickListener(
                OnMenuItemClickListener menuItemClickListener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setShortcut(char numericChar,
                char alphaChar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setShowAsAction(int actionEnum) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setShowAsActionFlags(int actionEnum) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setTitle(CharSequence title) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setTitle(int title) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setTitleCondensed(CharSequence title) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.MenuItem setVisible(boolean visible) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent c1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 1.class);
            startActivity(c1);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent c2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 5.class);
            startActivity(c2);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent c3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 3.class);
            startActivity(c3);
            break;
        case 4:
            Intent c4 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 4.class);
            startActivity(c4);
            break;
        default:
        }
    }
}

public void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.1);
        break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.2);
        break;
    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.3);
        break;
    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.4);
        break;
    default:
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By closing your application you delete all variables, including mIsPremium.

Therefor you need to save the value of mIsPremium somewhere and load it when you again open the application.

I suggest you to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this task.

That's how you could do this:

In the **IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener** you need to save your preference:

```
if (purchase.getSku().equals(PREM_SKU)) {
        // bought the premium upgrade!
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
        alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
        mIsPremium = true;
        mIsUserPremium = true;
        searchAllowed = true;
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "com.example.yourapp", 0);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("premium", true).apply;
}
```

Here you save the premium state "true" to the shared preference "premium" after the user has sucessfully purchased premium.

In the **onCreate()** method you need to load the preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.yourapp", 0);
mIsPremium = prefs.getBoolean("premium", false);
```

Here you load the preference "premium", if this prefernce does not exist yet, it will take "false" als default value.

Comment: i thought that when it inventories it will see the user has bought the app and set mIsPremium to true, or at least that is what i attempted to make happen.

Comment: This looks pretty clear now, I thought it would all be handled differently.  Quick question, why is it saved to true in the IabHelper, but then loaded as false in OnCreate?

Comment: It isn't loaded as "false". "false" is just the default value, if the preference "premium" does not exist, for example when the app is opened for the very first time.

Comment: I just noticed that, I should have read further.  One last question, could this be loaded in another class as well to show premium there too?

Comment: If the other class is an acitivity, you can always get it's application context by calling getApplicationContext(). So you can load/save the preferences there too. If it isn't an activtiy, you can pass the context to the new class.

Comment: Yes, its a new class that loads SherlockActivity.

Answer (score 2):

While the answers provided by both @Philip Sheard and @Al0x were excellent my problem was solved by a review of my code.  I entirely removed any reference to the "consume" process.  It was a simple fix but I also incorporated the SharedPreferences and all is well.  Thanks to all the suggestions - You led me to the correct places!

Comment: Exactly what the other guy says. You will have a lot of angry customers if you do not allow them to restore their purchases.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to add a button to your in-app store, that allows the user to restore all his purchases. This procedure is described in the IAB v3 docs, and Apple mandates such an approach.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what I am trying to do when I use `IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener()`?  Or should I be using `Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);` (Taken from [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html))

Comment: You are the only person who could possibly answer a question like that.

Comment: I dont think this is a good answer to this question. I mean we should probably writing a perfect code to keep the track of users

Comment: And what about Google? doesn't they maintain email accounts that have successfully placed the premium purchases?