# Purchased-inventory Collection not showing all Purchased products, Google Play In-App Billing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have implemented this project for in app billing https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3  .  Everything looks to work except not all Purchased Products are being returned for `Inventory` object.

I started with multiple products with id’s that have the same prefix, using a java package format

```
acmestudio.myapp.upgrade1.red
acmestudio.myapp.upgrade1.blue
acmestudio.myapp.upgrade1.green
```

This is where the issue started.  The first one I purchased, **acmestudio.myapp.upgrade1.red** worked and shows up in the purchased items for Inventory.

However, there after .. purchasing the other ones would:

- a) Get processed successfully,
- b) But not get returned subsequently in the list of Purchased productIds

I thought maybe it was a format issue, so I changed the dot-notation to be underscores.  However, again the same thing happened.    Now I have the multiple products with these id’s

```
acmestudio_myapp_upgrade1_red
acmestudio_myapp_upgrade1_blue
acmestudio_myapp_upgrade1_green
```

And again, it only worked for the 1st one.  So now in my list of purchased Skus, it has:
*[acmestudio.myapp.upgrade1.red, acmestudio_myapp_upgrade1_blue]*

And this happens, even though I see this **Order Confirmation** returned from the Billing API

```
PurchaseInfo:{"orderId":"GPA.1390-8158-3067-22151","packageName":"com.acmestudio.myapp”,
”productId":"acmestudio_myapp_upgrade1_red”,”purchaseTime":1455140848461,"purchaseState":0,
"purchaseToken":"akdnfgpkcnckkcdomomimihi.AO-J1OwKCGfAKHDDsBxbKjeVKRZ0hIOSXALhVPeYaKx2GsVGH6NbVDs4nj6sLf48oUy9Zs0MziVA7xFtebELB0Q6udcN_1fvaNynkFLVVJXJmZGeEiRy9c8KH7HIn2QK2SZc1EzB2NLtOoVu324s2EwPmmtLYKj6MA"}
```

I think I must be missing some step, because I set the debugger to stop here .. inside the github project code for IabHelper.java ..  that is, this issue is occuring in the code I haven’t even touched.
https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3/blob/master/src/com/android/vending/billing/util/IabHelper.java#L814

```
ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(
                    RESPONSE_INAPP_ITEM_LIST);
```

Here’s the code I run to check.  Notice I get 2 instances of an inventory object:

- 1. On main thread
- 2. In Asynch call

     ```
     List<String> moreSkus = null;
     Inventory inventory  = billingHelper.queryInventory(querySkuDetails, moreSkus);

     IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener inventoryLstnr = 
         new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

             @Override
             public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv)
             {
                 Log.d("Query inventory finished.");

                 // Is it a failure?
                 if (result.isFailure()) {
                         Log.d("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                     return;
                 }

                 Log.d("Query inventory was successful.");

             }

     };

     billingHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, inventoryLstnr);
     ```

What am I missing here? .. maybe I need unique prefixes?! I will try that next, but it seems it shouldn’t be the case that there would be an issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to SO's suggestions as I was posting this question, looks like the issue is related to `billingHelper.consumeAsync(..)` call.

By commenting that out, the product Ids that I am purchasing are appearing in the `inventory.mPurchaseMap`.

This post I finally stumbled upon explains it perfectly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452735/2162226

> *As the author puts nicely:*
>
> This is working as intended - in your code you are consuming the
> in-app purchase immediately, which means you can then purchase it
> again ..
>
> There's nothing that says you can't purchase a managed
> product more than once. What you can't do is purchase a managed
> product before a previous purchase of the same managed item has been
> consumed.

This post was SO's suggestion that I saw, and got me going in the right direction:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808407/2162226